# Getting a parameter in Oracle Reports from Oracle Forms

Tags: oracleforms, oraclereports

I want to pass a parameter using web.show_document() from a Form to a Report, I added the parameter in the URL but I don't know how to get it in the Report and use it .. anyone has an idea about that ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the parameters to report in Oracle Forms, you should use paramlist and pass it through run_report_object built-in and after that you can call the report using web.show_document by passing the report id. You can not pass report runtime parameters in web.show_document, below is the example:

```
pi_id := Create_parameter_list ('rep_param');

      Add_parameter (pi_id,
                     'PARAMFORM',
                     TEXT_PARAMETER,
                     'no');
      --- report object
      --- the below report object 'cproreport' must be created in Report object navigator.

      repid := Find_report_object ('cproreport');

      Set_report_object_property (repid, report_filename, Rtrim(:parameter.report_path)||preport);
      Set_report_object_property (repid, report_server, :parameter.r_server);
      Set_report_object_property (repid, report_execution_mode, RUNTIME);
      Set_report_object_property (repid, report_comm_mode, SYNCHRONOUS);
      Set_report_object_property (repid, report_destype, cache);
      Set_report_object_property (repid, report_desformat, pformat);

      vc_reportserverjob := Run_report_object (repid, pi_id);
```

After that run web.show_document as following:

```
report_job_id :=
         Substr (vc_reportserverjob,
                 Length (:parameter.r_server) + 2,
                 Length (vc_reportserverjob));
      v_rep_status := Report_object_status (vc_reportserverjob);

      If v_rep_status = 'FINISHED'
      Then
         web.show_document (
               'http://'
            || :parameter.host
            || ':'
            || :parameter.port
            || '/reports/rwservlet/getjobid'
            || report_job_id
            || '?server='
            || :parameter.r_server,
            '_blank'
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to run the report thru run_report_object first.  Simply create the parameter as a user parameter in report builder, e.g. P_EMPNO.  Then create your report url with the parameter and value.  The value will be passed to the report.
Run  web.show_document with the url
i.e.  ...?report_server=xxxxxxxx+report_id=myreport+P_EMPNO=0001.....